# output changes if font is defined inside a function and if inside __init__

Tags: python, tkinter

**What is my doubt**

I got two different outputs for two different codes which I believe are doing the same thing. I describe both the cases below.

## Case 1

**What I did**

I defined the following `__init__`

```
def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()  ##The main window instance
        self.window.title("STOPWATCH")

        ##Some fonts for use inside
        self.small = Font(family='Helvetica',size=11)
        self.medium = Font(family='Helvetica',size=15)
        self.big = Font(family='Helvetica',size=24)
```

And then used the `self.big` font inside a function of the class as so:

```
def quitwin(self,event=None):

        self.window.destroy()

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('License and Credits')
        
        self.frame =Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()

        r = Frame(self.frame)
        r.pack()

        m = Message(r,text="Licensed under WTFPL license\
                          ",font=self.big)

        m.pack()

        b = Button(r,text='QUIT',fg='red',bg='black',command=self.window.destroy,font=self.big)
        b.pack(side='bottom')
```

**Output:**

[image]

## Case 2

I changed the code so as to define the `self.big` varioable inside the function `quitwin` then:

**code:**

```
def quitwin(self,event=None):

        self.window.destroy()

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('License and Credits')
        
        self.frame =Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()

        r = Frame(self.frame)
        r.pack()

        self.big = Font(family='Helvetica',size=24)

        m = Message(r,text="Licensed under WTFPL license\
                              ",font=self.big)

        m.pack()

        b = Button(r,text='QUIT',fg='red',bg='black',command=self.window.destroy,font=self.big)
        b.pack(side='bottom')
```

**Output**

[image]

This font is much larger than the one what we saw before.

### Doubt

This set me wondering as to which of these is the real 24 size font. Though I do want the second output, Why am I not getting the same output with the code that I used first??

**Please** Help me out with this doubt.

Comment: if you don't assign self.big to the dialog in the first case, does the window still look like your first screenshot?

Comment: No sir. It is in the normal font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess it's related to the fact you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`, which is not how Tkinter is designed to be used. It could be that in the first case the font is tied to the original `Tk` object, and when that gets destroyed, the font gets corrupted or garbage collected. In the second case the font is tied to the same instance of `Tk` as the dialog so it is the "real size 24 font".